# How to play audio from a stream that contains a MPEG file?

Tags: c#, audio, stream, mpeg

My program receives MPEG audio as a stream and I want to play that stream as soon as it's received by the app. I am already familiar with SoundPlayer but it only supports .wav files and I've seen there isn't a lot of support for mpeg files.

Comment: There are probably many ways to do this, depending on the OS you're running on and the specific requirements of your app. Check out perhaps ffmpeg and for Windows APIs: [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk)

Comment: https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp might be easier than the ones suggested above.